# htaccess - allow access to one ip to url that starts with /sample/, restrict everything else

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make .htaccess block all ips (except one) to access any route that doesn't start with /sample/. For example:

`www.domain.com/ - unreachable to everyone`

`www.domain.com/test - unreachable to everyone`

`www.domain.com/sample/asdsd - reachable to one ip`

Heres what i got so far:

Block all access:

`Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all`

Check if url stars with /sample/ and allow specific ip to access it if so:

`<if url starts with www.domain.com/sample/>
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</if>`

I am basically stuck on the if statement.. any suggestions?

Comment: You should use a RewriteRule for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your root .htaccess you can do this using this `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sample/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```